# Installing Pynput won't work with python pip (Visual Studio Code)

Tags: python, pip

So I'm using Visual studio code's cmd terminal because my pc has cmd blocked and when i go do the install command `pip install pynput` to install pynput a error is occurring saying "Tunnel connection failed: 407 Proxy Authorization Required" What can i do to fix this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If our computer is connected to a proxy server, we will get this error.
The solution is we need our proxy username and password.
When we want to install the package we will solve the problem.
python get-pip.py --proxy="http://username:password@proxy.com:port"
pip install packageName --proxy="http://username:password@proxy.com:port"

Please fill in the username and password as related to you.

Answer (score 0):

try using:

python -m pip install pynput

or

pip3 install pynput

Comment: Sorry it won't work as it does the same as the command i used but thanks for trying to help

Answer (score 0):

error 407 means authentication for your proxy is either missing or wrong, to fix this use this command and fill in the blank as it relates to you

```
pip install --proxy https://username:pwd@proxy:host
```